# Failed to resolve: com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0 ....glide:3.7.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-volley, release, android-glide

'gradle' 'import' was done.
Then I got a problem. Help.

```
D:\bg.jou\GanggoContacts\build.gradle

Error:(25, 13) 

Failed to resolve: com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0
<a href="openFile:D:/bg.jou/GanggoContacts_v34_insert_error/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Error:(26, 13)

 Failed to resolve: com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0
<a href="openFile:D:/bg.jou/GanggoContacts_v34_insert_error/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

not complete problem

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}
```

---

```
dependencies {
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0'
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')

    compile project(':fingerpush_3.0.7')
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
}
```

Comment: The second `dependencies` is in which `build.gradle` file? Make sure it is inside the one which is inside `app` module.

Comment: 'gradle' is the only one at the 'app' level.

Answer (score 13):

[jcenter() is now deprecated.](https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown)

Use this in build.gradle of app:
`'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.0'`

And this in build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Answer (score 7):

One of the solutions below must solve your problem:

**1-** If you've added the following line in your "module/app" build.gradle,

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
```

you need to have the following code in your "project" build.gradle in order to enable your programming environment to find and download volley package

```
   allprojects {

    repositories {
         jcenter()
    }
}
```

**2-** You are living in a country which is under U.S. and International sanctions and that's why your programming environment cannot connect automatically to jcenter(bintray.com) to download the library, even though you've added jcenter to your repo list. If so, you have to use a proxy while syncing gradle.

Answer (score 4):

Add this snippet to your build.gradle file,

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

and replace with this -

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google() // Just google() will be fine
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}
```

If, you are using gradle version lower than 4.1 - replace 
`google()` 
with

```
maven {
    url 'https://maven.google.com'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to force the project to use the latest version of volley

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32773853)